# R output results in table

Tags: r

I'm working on a paper and I want to increase my productivity. For now, I run several functions such as unit root tests or correlation tests and transfer the **R** console output into a table; manually. Is there any way to output results from a function into a table?

I have following data from a *.csv table

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
x    x    x    x    x    x
x    x    x    x    x    x
x    x    x    x    x    x
x    x    x    x    x    x
```

1. Is it possible to apply `adf.test(table$col1)`, `kpss.test(table$col1)` and `pp.test(table$col1)` to all columns at once and output the results into a table?
2. Is it possible to do the same with correlation results like `cor.test(table$col1, table$col2, type="pearson")`?
3. I do know that I can use the stargazer package to export tables into latex. However, I would need to insert a table into word for now.

Comment: Can you show some desired output? What you're describing is certainly possible, but depends on what exactly you're doing. While I know that there are packages for r and word, I personally use xtable to write to a html-file (as that's easily copy-pasted when you're happy with the result).

Comment: See [r markdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/)

Comment: @Heroka, HTML output sounds fine! For unit root tests, for example, the table should output each variable's (column's) result without trend, with constant and constant and trend plus each t-statistic and p-value. I used AIC for testing. I guess marking p-values isn't that easy either?

Comment: @zx8754 do you have an example?

Comment: You are asking for too many things in one post, as I see, you need as an end result a report in Word document. Answer is yes, it can be done using markdown.

Comment: `stargazer` could export to `htm` files as well (not just latex) which could be easily loaded to Word. Just use the option `type="html"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Since you can access each element of your output separately (e.g. `cor.test( )["statistic"]` to get the t-value from your correlation.), you can simply write a function to put each of the elements you are interested in into a table, then output it with [Markdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) to Word.

For example in your Markdown document suppose you have this data:

````
title: "stackexchange"
author: "you"
date: "September 13, 2015"
output: word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE, message = FALSE, echo = FALSE}
library(knitr)
set.seed(1)
source( "~/Dropbox/R_Default/MyRTools/DinkyTools/EmptyFrame.R")
df <- data.frame( a = runif( n = 100, min = -1000, max = 1000 ),
              b = rnorm( n = 100, mean = 0, sd = 500 ),
              c = rlogis( n = 100, location = 50, scale = 100 ) )

table_cols <- c( correlation = "character", 
             estimate = "numeric",
             t_value = "numeric", 
             p_value = "numeric", 
             CI_l_95 = "numeric", 
             CI_u_95 = "numeric" )

nvar <- c(1:3)
cmb <- combn( nvar , m = 2)
````

Then use whatever method you prefer to create an empty data frame for your table. I have my own script to create empty data frames, but whatever gets you something like this is fine:

```
tbl <- EmptyFrame( rows = ncol( cmb ), varnames_and_types = table_cols ,     print.opt = TRUE) 

>correlation estimate t_value p_value CI_l_95 CI_u_95
1        <NA>       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
2        <NA>       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
3        <NA>       NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
[1] "correlation  :  character"
[1] "estimate  :  numeric"
[1] "t_value  :  numeric"
[1] "p_value  :  numeric"
[1] "CI_l_95  :  numeric"
[1] "CI_u_95  :  numeric"
```

The effort is then to write some generic function for your output. For example, if I like all pairwise correlations, I say something like:

````
for( ii in 1 : nrow( tbl ) ){
  tbl$correlation[ ii ] <- paste("cor.test of", names( df )[cmb[ 1, ii] ], "     with ", names( df )[cmb[ 2, ii] ] )
  tbl$estimate[ ii ] <- round( as.numeric( cor.test ( df[ , cmb[ 1, ii ] ], df[ , cmb[2 , ii] ] )[[ "estimate" ]] ), 2)
  tbl$t_value[ ii ] <- round( as.numeric( cor.test ( df[ , cmb[ 1, ii ] ], df[ , cmb[2 , ii] ] )[[ "statistic" ]] )  , 2)
  tbl$p_value[ ii ] <- round( as.numeric( cor.test ( df[ , cmb[ 1, ii ] ], df[ , cmb[2 , ii] ] )[[ "p.value" ]] ), 2)  
  tbl$CI_l_95[ ii ] <- round( cor.test ( df[ , cmb[ 1, ii ] ], df[ , cmb[2 , ii] ] )[[ "conf.int" ]][1] , 2)
  tbl$CI_u_95[ ii ] <- round( cor.test ( df[ , cmb[ 1, ii ] ], df[ , cmb[2 , ii] ] )[[ "conf.int" ]][2], 2)
}
```
````

This gives you a table, which will compile in Markdown to word.

````
```{r}
kable( tbl )  
|correlation            | estimate| t_value| p_value| CI_l_95| CI_u_95|
|:----------------------|--------:|-------:|-------:|-------:|-------:|
|cor.test of a  with  b |     0.09|    0.88|    0.38|   -0.11|    0.28|
|cor.test of a  with  c |    -0.17|   -1.74|    0.08|   -0.36|    0.02|
|cor.test of b  with  c |    -0.02|   -0.23|    0.82|   -0.22|    0.17|

```
````

b) Yes. Generally you use `apply(X, MARGIN, FUN, ...)` to run functions over all columns of a data frame.

c) Seems to me you will be really love using [Markdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/).